# Antonym or similar of 'corollary' - when it comes to popular proverbs

Tags: single-word-requests

Specifically I'm thinking of the proverb:

> What is popular is not always right, what is right is not always popular.

The *caveat* I would add to this is

> But just because something is popular, doesn't mean it is wrong. Just because something is unpopular, doesn't mean it is right.

Is there a particular word better than caveat that works here?

Comment: A _corollary_ is a small theorem that follows at once from a major theorem. For instance, every proverb that has the form "If A, then B" has a corollary contrapositive proverb "If Not B, then Not A". My favorite is "If it's not worth doing well, it's not worth doing at all".

Comment: Caveat is as good as any; but you could use a thesaurus for alternatives. https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/caveat